# I can browse any website except of Facebook and Youtube

Tags: 14.04, internet, dns

I have Ubuntu and archlinux running on different boxes. Along with and Android phone. which i can't open Facebook or Youtube in the browsers (Firefox, Chrome). Error message: *Server not found.*

I can browse all other website I could try. https and http.

One of the boxes dual boots Windows 10. On that installation I was able to access both normally. Other computers in the house using the same router and Internet connection which has Windows and OS X are able to browse both websites normal.

I have changed my DNS settings to GoogleDNS and OpenDNS which in both cases didn't solve the problem. I have tried the drop the MTU values and it did work. I have restarted the router multiple times and it didn't work.

I can ping facebook.com and youtube.com and the packets are normal. I have managed to open m.facebook.com and it works normal but not m.youtube.com

this is a `$dig www.facebook.com` result http://pastebin.com/PZGhhA9S
Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: Try deleting your internet caches - works for me when I have problems with browsers.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I have tried that as well. and i tried it again now without any success..